# how to covert 2:30 am to 02:30 am with php

Tags: php, time

How can I add a leading zero in a time, such as converting "2:30 am" to "02:30 am"? so that I can validate the string format?

Answer (score 0):

You can check out this [link](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.time.php). It has the time formats for the php. You can use them as you like.

Comment: This is a link only answer. Providing a list to the time formats does not answer the question directly.

Answer (score 0):

I found something online. Maybe this can help you on your way.

```
<?php

    $date = date_create("2012-03-24 5:45:12");

    echo date_format($date, 'H:ia');
    #output: 05:45am

    echo date_format($date, 'H:i A');
    #output: 05:45 AM

?>
```

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php